# PyGame - Image stopped moving after new image is created

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I've a simple `PyGame` game taken from the net where I'm doing some changes in order to learn game programing.

It's a very simple game. A character (class `Player`) is shown in the level, and if you press `CTRL` he *shoots* a bullet (it's an image loaded from the  `Bullet` class). The bullet just takes the position of the character and increments it's `X` axis (moves horizontaly) until forever.

If I push, for example, two times `CTRL`, the first bullet gets stucked, and the second bullet keeps moving until I press again `CTRL`, and so on.

This is my code so far. Im sorry for posting everything but as I'm new in `PyGame` I can't difference which can be relevant code for the problem or not.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import pygame
from pygame import *

#WIN_WIDTH = 800
#WIN_HEIGHT = 640
WIN_WIDTH = 400
WIN_HEIGHT = 340
HALF_WIDTH = int(WIN_WIDTH / 2)
HALF_HEIGHT = int(WIN_HEIGHT / 2)

DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)
DEPTH = 32
FLAGS = 0
CAMERA_SLACK = 30

def main():
    global cameraX, cameraY
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, FLAGS, DEPTH)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Use arrows to move!")
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()

    up = down = left = right = running = shoot = False
    bg = Surface((32,32))
    bg.convert()
    bg.fill(Color("#000000"))
    entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player = Player(32, 32)
    #bullet = Bullet(30,7)
    platforms = []

    x = y = 0
    level = [
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P         PP         PPPPPPPPPPP           P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P    PPPPPPPP                              P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                          PPPPPPP         P",
        "P                 PPPPPP                   P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P         PPPPPPP                          P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                     PPPPPP               P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P   PPPPPPPPPPP                            P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                 PPPPPPPPPPP              P",
        "P                                          P",
        "P                                          E",
        "P                                          E",
        "P                                          E",
        "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",]
    # build the level
    for row in level:
        for col in row:
            if col == "P":
                p = Platform(x, y)
                platforms.append(p)
                entities.add(p)
            if col == "E":
                e = ExitBlock(x, y)
                platforms.append(e)
                entities.add(e)
            x += 32
        y += 32
        x = 0

    total_level_width  = len(level[0])*32
    total_level_height = len(level)*32
    camera = Camera(complex_camera, total_level_width, total_level_height)
    entities.add(player)

    while 1:
        timer.tick(60)

        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == QUIT: raise SystemExit, "QUIT"
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_ESCAPE:
                raise SystemExit, "ESCAPE"
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_UP:
                up = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_DOWN:
                down = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_SPACE:
                running = True
            if e.type == KEYDOWN and e.key == K_LCTRL:
                shoot = True
                player_pos = player.returnPlayerPos()
                bullet = Bullet(player_pos[0]+50, player_pos[1]+30)
                entities.add(bullet)

            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_UP:
                up = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_DOWN:
                down = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_RIGHT:
                right = False
            if e.type == KEYUP and e.key == K_LEFT:
                left = False

        # draw background
        for y in range(32):
            for x in range(32):
                screen.blit(bg, (x * 32, y * 32))
        camera.update(player)
        #camera.update(bullet)

        # update player, draw everything else
        player.update(up, down, left, right, running, platforms)

        # update bullet
        if shoot == True:
            bullet.update()

        for e in entities:
            screen.blit(e.image, camera.apply(e))
        pygame.display.update()


class Camera(object):
    def __init__(self, camera_func, width, height):
        self.camera_func = camera_func
        self.state = Rect(0, 0, width, height)

    def apply(self, target):
        return target.rect.move(self.state.topleft)

    def update(self, target):
        self.state = self.camera_func(self.state, target.rect)

def simple_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    return Rect(-l+HALF_WIDTH, -t+HALF_HEIGHT, w, h)

def complex_camera(camera, target_rect):
    l, t, _, _ = target_rect
    _, _, w, h = camera
    l, t, _, _ = -l+HALF_WIDTH, -t+HALF_HEIGHT, w, h

    l = min(0, l)                           # stop scrolling at the left edge
    l = max(-(camera.width-WIN_WIDTH), l)   # stop scrolling at the right edge
    t = max(-(camera.height-WIN_HEIGHT), t) # stop scrolling at the bottom
    t = min(0, t)                           # stop scrolling at the top
    return Rect(l, t, w, h)

class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

class Player(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.xvel = 0
        self.yvel = 0
        self.onGround = False
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/character.png')  # @UndefinedVariable
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 75, 89)


    def update(self, up, down, left, right, running, platforms):
        if up:
            # only jump if on the ground
            if self.onGround: self.yvel -= 10
        if down:
            pass
        if running:
            self.xvel = 12
        if left:
            self.xvel = -8
        if right:
            self.xvel = 8
        if not self.onGround:
            # only accelerate with gravity if in the air
            self.yvel += 0.3
            # max falling speed
            if self.yvel > 100: self.yvel = 100
        if not(left or right):
            self.xvel = 0
        # increment in x direction
        self.rect.left += self.xvel 
        # do x-axis collisions
        self.collide(self.xvel, 0, platforms)
        # increment in y direction
        self.rect.top += self.yvel
        # assuming we're in the air
        self.onGround = False;
        # do y-axis collisions
        self.collide(0, self.yvel, platforms)

    def returnPlayerPos(self):
        m = []
        m.append(self.rect[0])
        m.append(self.rect[1])
        return m  

    def collide(self, xvel, yvel, platforms):
        for p in platforms:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, p):
                if isinstance(p, ExitBlock):
                    pygame.event.post(pygame.event.Event(QUIT))
                if xvel > 0:
                    self.rect.right = p.rect.left
                    print "collide right"
                if xvel < 0:
                    self.rect.left = p.rect.right
                    print "collide left"
                if yvel > 0:
                    self.rect.bottom = p.rect.top
                    self.onGround = True
                    self.yvel = 0
                if yvel < 0:
                    self.rect.top = p.rect.bottom

class Bullet(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/bullet.png')  
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 30, 7)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.right += 4


class Platform(Entity):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Entity.__init__(self)
        self.image = Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.convert()
        self.image.fill(Color("#DDDDDD"))
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)

    def update(self):
        pass

class ExitBlock(Platform):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        Platform.__init__(self, x, y)
        self.image.fill(Color("#0033FF"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

So I want to know if someone can give me a hand and tell me how can I shoot *unlimited* bullets in my game and keep all of the moving horizontally at the same time, and not only one.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is at lines 101 and 124

```
bullet = Bullet(player_pos[0]+50, player_pos[1]+30)
entities.add(bullet)
...
# update bullet
if shoot == True:
    bullet.update()
```

You add the new bullet to the entities list (line 102).  However, when it comes time to move the bullets (line 125), you move only the most recent one (bullet is the newest).

You have to update every bullet in the list until they move off screen.

I won't do a full code review here; we have a separate group for that.  However, note that "== True" is *always* redundant.  Here, just say "if shoot:"

Comment: I archieved it by making a bullet list and adding all the bullets to the list. Then, `updating` every `bullet` from the list.